# How to Center JButtons in a centered JLabel in a BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, boxlayout

I'm new in Java GUI programming and I have a strange issue with the `BoxLayout`:
I have an `JLabel` with an `Icon`. Added to the label are two `JButtons`. The `Jlabel` is placed in the `CENTER` position of the `BorderLayout` from a `JFrame`. Now I want that these two `JButtons` are always in the center of the `JLabel` even when I resize the `JFrame`. With `setAlignmentX()` the Jbuttons are centered horizontally , but there is no solution with `setAlignmentY()` for the vertical direction.

here is the code:

```
package footballQuestioner;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Houdini {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new House();
    }

    }

    class House extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel(
            new ImageIcon(
                    "C:\\Users\\laudatio\\Documents\\Java\\MyProject\\src\\footballQuestioner\\footballfield.jpg")
            );
    private JButton one=new  JButton("one");
    private JButton two=new JButton("two");


    public House() {


        label.setLayout(new BoxLayout(label, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        label.add(one);
        label.add(two);

        one.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        one.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        two.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        two.setAlignmentY(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);


        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setLocation(300, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);

        add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Please Help! :-((((

Comment: Use `GridBagLayout` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but there is no solution with setAlignmentY() for the vertical direction.

Use "glue" before and after your two components. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.

Although MadProgrammers comment to use a `GridBagLayout` is an easier solution, but knowing about "glue" and "struts" can be helpful for customizing the layout of a `BoxLayout`.